# Update config in a docker container with command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a MyAppName.config.json file in my app that keeps the connection string to db:

```
{
  "DbConnectionString": "Server=(local);Database=Test;User ID=sa;Password=test;max pool size=1000"
}
```

I want to replace the server name in that config from `(local)` to 'sql-server-db'.
My compose file:

```
 my-service:
        container_name: my-service
        image: my-service:1.0
        environment:               
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
        depends_on:
            - sql-server-db    
        ports:
            - "5001:80"
        command: /bin/bash -c 'sed -i 's/(local)/sql-server-db/' MyAppName.config.json'
```

I tried to explore service files after composing with such commands:

```
docker exec -t -i my-service /bin/bash
cat MyAppName.config.json
```

And the SQL server name still the same. Then I ran `sed -i 's/(local)/sql-server-db/' MyAppName.config.json` command manually and the server name has been changed.

Is there a way to change the value in the config during compose?

Comment: You can add an entrypoint script to your docker-compose config, see

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint

Comment: Is the image one you built yourself?  Can you change it to take the configuration as an environment variable, or change the _image's_ entrypoint to do the replacement before running its command?

Comment: I can not change the image or the configuration to use environment variable

Comment: I tried to override the entrypoint, but still no result:
 entrypoint: ["dotnet", "MyAppName.dll", "/bin/bash"]
 command: /bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/(local)/sql-server-db/' MyAppName.config.json"